# why does NPM start give me the error of Module Not Found

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-start

I am using vs code right now. So I first did `npm init`, then I installed parcel and sass. Using `npm i parcel@next -D` and `npm i sass@next -D`. No errors until now.

Then I went into the package.json file and replaced the test in the scripts object to `'start':'parcel index.html'`. And after that, I wrote this script in terminal `npm start`, I got this weird error, that says `[module_not_found]`[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZKTR.png).

Here is a screenshot. I have some SASS files, and I want to make then into 1 CSS file.

Comment: Which node version are you using? parcel requires node 12+ to run correctly.

Comment: It happen when we define node module in our code but forgot to install or add that module in package.json file

Comment: i have node 14.16.0

Comment: The error says that there are 4 JS files missing. But when I click on the link it opens a file. This is a project that I am still building, so there are still 0 js files. Only sass files.

Comment: Please share your index.html and file structure with sass files

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wpeVq_O7nX034jGWVkViIkGY49ulhRHt?usp=sharing